# How to rewrite this Anonymous Function code to work with PHP versions before 5.3?

Tags: php, compatibility, php-5.3, anonymous-function, php-5.2

I've added this small function to stop WordPress from checking for updates. However in PHP version less than PHP 5.3 anonymous functions don't work. I don't actually understand the purpose of an anonymous function in the code bellow so would rather ask here - how do I rewrite this code to work with PHP version before 5.3?

```
$func = function($a){
    global $wp_version;
    return (object) array(
        'last_checked' => time(),
        'version_checked' => $wp_version,
    );
};
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', $func);
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', $func);
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', $func);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php) which has been around since PHP 4.

```
$func = create_function(
    '$a',
    'global $wp_version; return (object)array("last_checked" => time(), "version_checked" => $wp_version);'
);

add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', $func);
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', $func);
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', $func);
```

Anonymous function in WordPress are bad practice however. The nice thing about hooks is that the end user (or just someone other than the plugin/theme author) can remove the callbacks if they want. You can't do that with an anonymous function unless you keep a reference to it around some place.  In this case, it would probably be better to just use a real function.

```
function so19590942_check_version($a)
{
    global $wp_version;
    return (object) array(
        'last_checked' => time(),
        'version_checked' => $wp_version,
    );
}

add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', 'so19590942_check_version');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_plugins', 'so19590942_check_version');
add_filter('pre_site_transient_update_themes', 'so19590942_check_version');
```

Which lets another plugin/theme author or end user do something like...

```
remove_filter('pre_site_transient_update_core', 'so19590942_check_version');
```

If they don't like what you've done in `so19590942_check_version`.